# Tensorflow with output specified as integer or float

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on applying DL to a regression problem and some of the outputs need to be integers while others can be floats. So far I have built a NN which returns floats for all but I want to go to the next step and actually return ints vs floats for the different outputs.

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521001/tensorflow-error-producing-result-on-a-single-dataset) I asked a question where I provided a simple example of regression for `y = m * x + b` which I was able to solve on my own. In this example, how would the code be changed to ensure `b` is integer while `m` is float?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#################
### CONSTANTS ###
#################
ARANGE = (-5.0, 5.0) # Possible values for m in training data
BRANGE = (0.0, 10.0) # Possible values for b in training data
X_MIN = 1.0 
X_MAX = 9.0 
N = 10 # Number of grid points
M = 2 # Number of {(x,y)} sets to train on


def gen_ab(arange, brange):
    """ mrange, brange are tuples of floats """
    a = (arange[1] - arange[0])*np.random.rand() + arange[0]
    b = (brange[1] - brange[0])*np.random.rand() + brange[0]

    return (a, b)

def build_model(x_data, y_data):
    """ Build the model using input / output training data
    Args:
        x_data (np array): Size (m, n*2) grid of input training data.
        y_data (np array): Size (m, 2) grid of output training data.
    Returns:
        model (Sequential model)
    """
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=len(x_data[0])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(len(y_data[0])))

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

    return model


def gen_data(xs, arange, brange, m):
    """ Generate training data for lines of y = m*x + b
    Args:
        xs (list): Grid points (size N1)
        arange (tuple): Range to use for a (a_min, a_max)
        brange (tuple): Range to use for b (b_min, b_max)
        m (int): Number of y grids to generate
    Returns:
        x_data (np array): Size (m, n*2) grid of input training data.
        y_data (np array): Size (m, 2) grid of output training data.
    """
    n = len(xs)
    x_data = np.zeros((m, 2*n))
    y_data = np.zeros((m, 2))
    for ix in range(m):
        (a, b) = gen_ab(arange, brange)
        ys = a*xs + b*np.ones(xs.size)
        x_data[ix, :] = np.concatenate((xs, ys))
        y_data[ix, :] = [a, b]

    return (x_data, y_data)

def main():
    """ Main routin """
    # Generate the x axis grid to be used for all training sets
    xs = np.linspace(X_MIN, X_MAX, N)

    # Generate the training data
    # x_train has M rows (M is the number of training samples)
    # x_train has 2*N columns (first N columns are x, second N columns are y)
    # y_train has M rows, each of which has two columns (a, b) for y = ax + b
    (x_train, y_train) = gen_data(xs, ARANGE, BRANGE, M)

    model = build_model(x_train, y_train)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    model.summary()

    ####################
    ### Test example ###
    ####################
    (a, b) = gen_ab(ARANGE, BRANGE)
    ys = a*xs + b*np.ones(xs.size)
    rys = np.concatenate((xs, ys))
    ab1 = model.predict(x_train)
    ab2 = model.predict(np.array([rys]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be possible but actually not as trivial as it sounds. You unfortunately can't simply get the NN to output an int and a float and use the normal MSE loss you are using as the discreet nature of the int values prevents the loss function being continuously differentiable like the optimisers need.

If one really wanted to do it they could treat the int output variable as if it were actually a multi class output (treating the float output the same). You would need to craft a loss function out of the combination of these two outputs (multi class + float). You could one-hot-encode and then softmax the multi class outputs. An interesting complication of this is that the neural network would not know that the multi class output is actually ordinal (ordered, since 1<2<3<4 etc.). There have been interesting attempts in the past to help NNs to realise this (see [Neural Network Ordinal Classification for Age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375401/neural-network-ordinal-classification-for-age)).